# Installing Node version 10 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, ubuntu-18.04

I have tried installing Node version 10 on Ubuntu 18.04 using-

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash`

```
sudo apt install nodejs
```

But this keeps installing Node v 8.10 instead of version 10.
Also, the command
"`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash`"
 gives error:

```
Err:5 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
Reading package lists... Done                                  
W: GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Can anyone tell me an exact way to install Node version 10 please.

Comment: It might not be what you are looking for, but I always suggest using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install Node. It makes it really easy to switch between versions, and allows for different Node versions between users.

Comment: Adding to Seblor's comment, you can also use [n](https://github.com/tj/n) for installing and managing different version for node. If you want to go manually, [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957439/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-node-on-ubuntu-server) should work for you (just change the proper version names from [here](https://nodejs.org/dist)).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v

Output >>>v8.10.0
sudo apt install npm
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh

nano /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt install nodejs
node -v
Output
v17.3.0
```